# clicktale.com alternative that works with https and ajax

Tags: analytics

I need to record user's actions on site for analytics purposes. The way clicktale.com doing it is just fine. But unfortunately it have problems with working over https and recording ajax events.

Is there some service or script/library that I can host that can do this task? Non-free one's are ok to.

Clarification: ClickTale function that I want to reproduce is recording of separate user sessions and their replay. So you can see video of all user's interactions with page: There he clicks first, which links opens, etc. Usually such services replay user's actions buy reproducing them with javascript (and here comes ajax problem: external sites can't use ajax because of cross-domain scripting). So I'm looking for a tool (possibly script that I host on site to allow cross-domain scripting) that can record ajax blocks actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [sessioncam.com](http://www.sessioncam.com) for this type of problem. It works really well for ajax session replay and there's a free account option.

Answer (score 0):

I also used SessionCam, and can confirm it's does exactly what it's designed to do, was easy to install and is  one of my best analytics tools...